# Is it possible to gather live network traffic using only the TCL standard library?

Tags: unix, tcl

I am working on a project with a couple other people and we've run into an issue where we need to check if a a device is contacting a certain address of a server we're running on our machine.

We currently do some post processing with wireshark captures, but recently we've been interested in seeing if we could do it live.

The only caveat is that our only resource is the standard TCL library (i.e. we cannot download any extra packages for TCL or the OS.

I've been looking around in the internet category on the TCL wiki and have yet to see anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only network traffic that baseline Tcl will work with is that sent by or to TCP sockets that it created (ultimately with the `socket` command, though many packages wrap around it). Listening to other types of sockets or other traffic that wasn't intended for the Tcl code (e.g., with a “promiscuous mode” network card) requires some sort of extension, or that the listening be done in another process.

Comment: Tcl 8.6 does support both the IPv4 and IPv6 network-level addressing protocols, but that won't affect the answer to your fundamental question: ___NO___, Tcl doesn't do that on its own.

Comment: Drat, thanks for the quick response guys. Back to the drawing board!